# HTML attributes (width, height) of canvas change independently

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, canvas

I have some script on JS, it change width and height of canvas element:

```
 function RefreshSizes (canvas) {
        var temp_width = 320;
        var temp_height = 240;

        document.getElementById(canvas).setAttribute('width', temp_width);
        document.getElementById(canvas).setAttribute('height', temp_height);
    }
```

this functions calling right after canvas initializing.
It works fine on Chrome.

But in FireFox 49 I see that:

[image]

What could it be?

UPD#1 Tested code of BukkitmanPlays MCPE
[image]

UPD#2
Full CSS for canvas:

```
    element {
        width: 320px;
        height: 240px;
    }
    .canvas {
        border: 3px solid #E0E0E0;
        z-index: 0;
        position: relative;
    }
    html {
        font: 10px/10px arial;
    }
```

Comment: Btw, it is not depends of initializing in HTML: 
<canvas id="canvas1" class="canvas" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
  <canvas id="canvas2" class="canvas"></canvas>

Comment: Please consider providing a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: You are not passing any arguments to `RefreshSizes()`. Nothing will happen.

Comment: Sorry Salman but I think you are not right now, first example need argument, but second example don't need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

some code on one browser isn't the same on another browser, so in this case, what I would do:

```
function RefreshSizes (canv) {
    var temp_width = 320;
    var temp_height = 240;

    var canvas = canv;
    canvas.width = temp_width;
    canvas.height = temp_height;
}
```

I'm sure this will work